# Size of newly created table is less than base table though having the same amount of data

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a base table "**FND_LOG_MESSAGES**" whose size is **1422 MB**.
Now I have created a table "**XXARG_GOKU_DBZ**".

I created the table from XXARG_GOKU_DBZ from FND_LOG_MESSAGES with the below query.

```
SQL> create table XXARG_GOKU_DBZ as select * from FND_LOG_MESSAGES;
    Table created.

SQL> commit;
    Commit complete.
```

But XXARG_GOKU_DBZ size is **43.625 MB**

```
 SQL> select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024 MB from dba_segments where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='XXARG_GOKU_DBZ';

SEGMENT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEGMENT_TYPE                                                   MB
------------------------------------------------------ ----------
XXARG_GOKU_DBZ
TABLE                                                      43.625


SQL> select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024 MB from dba_segments where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='FND_LOG_MESSAGES';

SEGMENT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEGMENT_TYPE                                                   MB
------------------------------------------------------ ----------
FND_LOG_MESSAGES
TABLE                                                        1422
```

Anyone please explain me why this is happening ?

Both the tables has the same amount of data.

```
SQL> select count(*) from XXARG_GOKU_DBZ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    129304

SQL>  select count(*) from FND_LOG_MESSAGES;


  COUNT(*)
----------
    129304
```

Comment: A block will have data in it until it reaches the `PCTUSED` limit (for manually managed tablespaces). When a row is deleted from a block then it leaves space. That free space will not be reused until sufficient deletions have been performed to take the block down below the `PCTFREE` limit; at which point the block will re-enter circulation and can be refilled (up to the `PCTUSED` limit). Your old table has probably had lots of deletions so there are many blocks that are not as full as could be; whereas the new table has its blocks packed with little/no free space below the high water mark.

Comment: It's worth remembering that running a DDL statement causes the DB to perform a commit therefore the COMMIT after the CTAS is unnecessary.

Comment: @BriteSponge : Thanks for the tip !!

Comment: Your new table may also be using compression